# Make a discord.js command only available to owner

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently using a say command on my discord bot, but want to make it only available to me. The normal command runs fine, but once I insert "if (message.author.id !== '411308845714112513') return;" then it doesn't work. Here's the original code below for reference, I got it from another post on here and I've tested it out and it works fine:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "say",
  description: "Send a message via the bot",
 async execute(message, args){

    const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    message.channel.send(`${sayMessage}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it for my bot. This first way uses permissions the second way uses roles.

Permissions:

```
 if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("I cannot let you do that");
```

Role:

```
        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('758292763946123295')){
 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was absolutely correct. Including
`if(message.author.id!=='yourid') return;`
should work. Make sure you entered the correct ID. Also make sure that the that this condition is before the command handler itself.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm doing this right, would it look like this?

`const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "say",
  description: "Send a message via the bot",
  async execute(message, args){
  if (message.author.id !== '411308845714112513') return;

   const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    message.channel.send(`${sayMessage}`);
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

When I do this, I usually use if else. For example:

```
if (message.author.id === 'your id here') {
//only executes if the author is you
} else {
//only executes if the author is not you
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You all have to do is define your id and change the id with defined variable in "if (message.author.id !== '411308845714112513') return;"

This will be the preview:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ownersId = "YOUR ID HERE"
    
module.exports = {
name: "say",
description: "Send a message via the bot",
async execute(message, args){
  if (message.author.id !== ownersId) return; // Replace your id with defined variable
  const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
  message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
  message.channel.send(`${sayMessage}`);
 }
}
```